# Certain map of modules is iso [Mumford Abelian Varieties]

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, abelian-varieties

I have trouble showing the following in the proof of Prop. 2 in *Abelian Varieties* (pg.70 my edition, Chapter about quotients by finite groups):

Suppose you have a Noetherian ring $B=A^G$ as invariants of some action of a finite group on a Noetherian ring $A$. Also $A$ is finite over $B$ as module. The following map, which I suppose is multiplication is claimed to be an iso:

$N^G\otimes_B A \to N$ for $N$ an $A$-module with $G$-action.

My problem is that I don't understand how to prove the following special case:

Let $A\simeq B^k$ and suppose $G$ acts simply transitive by permutations. Then Mumford says it's obvious that the map is an iso.
I guess I understand the thinking behind it, i.e. recovering the orbits of the non-invariant elements in $N$, but I have trouble to write down a map which does that.

Comment: In this case I think the upshot is that $A^G = B$, embedded diagonally, and $N \simeq (N^G)^k$. If this is true then I agree with Mumford that the isomorphism is obvious. Maybe I can write it out later. This is a hard book.